# How to simplify analytic expression without introducing Abs[]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, complex, expression-manipulation

I am working with analytical expressions that, as you will see from `expr` below, stem from certain expressions involving `Abs[]`. However, for further calculus I do not want `Abs[]` to appear in my expressions, so that I use `ComplexExpand[]` to get rid of it. Yet, there are terms in the `ComplexExpand`ed expressions that are certainly zero, but Mathematica does not realize this immediately during the evaluation...

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
$Assumptions = Element[{f1, f2, th, gb, wb, eb, deg, dwe, dwg}, Reals];

(* shorthand notation *)
sx = PauliMatrix[1];
sy = PauliMatrix[2];
sz = PauliMatrix[3];
id = PauliMatrix[0];

(* define some stuff *)
a1 = 2*Sqrt[wb^2 + gb^2 + dwg^2];
n1 = {gb, dwg, wb}/(a1/2);
u1 = Cos[a1/2]*id - I*n1.{sx, sy, sz}*Sin[a1/2];
unitaryD = {{Exp[-I*f1]*Cos[th], -Exp[I*f2]*Sin[th]}, {Exp[-I*f2]*Sin[th], Exp[I*f1]*Cos[th]}};
```

Now evaluate `expr = ComplexExpand[Abs[Tr[u1.unitaryD]]]` and observe that `Simplify@expr[[1, 1]]` is zero. So `expr` could actually be written much shorter... However, a naive `Simplify@expr` returns an expression involving `Abs` again. How can I avoid this? I am pretty sure the most obvious method is the `TransformationFunctions` option of `Simplify`, but I am absolutely clueless about how to use it.

[image]

For reference: happens on Mathematica 10.0.1 on Gentoo Linux 64bit

Edit: While replacing greek symbols for readability reasons, I forgot to replace one `\[Alpha]` which caused the `Abs` not to appear. Sorry for that.

Comment: no expression with `Abs` is produced for me if I run `Simplify@expr`. This is what I get: `2 \[Sqrt]((
   1/(\[Alpha]1^2))((\[Alpha]1 Cos[f1] Cos[th] Cos[Sqrt[
       dwg^2 + gb^2 + wb^2]] - 
     2 (wb Cos[th] Sin[f1] + (dwg Cos[f2] + gb Sin[f2]) Sin[th]) Sin[
       Sqrt[dwg^2 + gb^2 + wb^2]])^2))`

Comment: @glS Hm that's weird. I have already left office but will try on my desktop machine at home. Issue happens on Linux 64bit, MMA 10.0.1

Comment: I get the same expression as glS on a Linux 64 bit MMA 10.2.0.0

Comment: The closest version I have is v10.0.2.0 on a Mac. I do not see an `Abs` in `expr` and `Simplify` works fine with it. Perhaps you need to add the option `TargetFunctions->{Re, Im}` to your `ComplexExpand`

Comment: No `Abs` on MMA 10.4.1, Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: @BobHanlon @corey979 @glS @andy269 Checked on v10.0.1 on my Windows 8 64bit, no `Abs`. I will have to debug this further as soon as I am back to office...

Comment: How are you taking `expr[[1,1]]` when `expr` is a scalar?

Comment: @Myridium `Part` acts on the `FullForm` of the expression. It is no limited to lists. This is also explained quite at the bottom of the details section in the docs for `Part`

Comment: @Lukas - Huh, okay. As for suggestions, it's a stab in the dark but maybe try `Simplify[expr, ComplexityFunction->LeafCount]` or some other `ComplexityFunction`. I can't reproduce the problem (Linux x64, MMA 11.0) so can't test it myself.

Comment: @glS I forgot to replace one greek symbol while copying from my notebook to SE. This prevented `Abs` from appearing in the expression. Now the problem should be comprehensible.

Comment: @BobHanlon I forgot to replace one greek symbol while copying from my notebook to SE. This prevented `Abs` from appearing in the expression. Now the problem should be comprehensible.

Comment: @corey979 I forgot to replace one greek symbol while copying from my notebook to SE. This prevented `Abs` from appearing in the expression. Now the problem should be comprehensible.

Comment: @andy269 I forgot to replace one greek symbol while copying from my notebook to SE. This prevented `Abs` from appearing in the expression. Now the problem should be comprehensible.

Comment: @Myridium  I forgot to replace one greek symbol while copying from my notebook to SE. This prevented `Abs` from appearing in the expression. Now the problem should be comprehensible. Unfortunately, your suggestion about `ComplexityFunction` does not solve the issue (as far as I could try due to limited knowledge about it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I provide the same input as you, my result is the same. Now when we look at `expr[[1,1]]`:

[image]

I notice that this has *already been simplified to 0* when we simplify `expr`. Compare the expressions:

[image]

So it seems to me that `Simplify@expr` *can't* be written any shorter as you say. I can only surmise that your problem with the output of `Simplify@expr` then is just that there's an `Abs` in there. Well that can be removed quite easily by another application of `ComplexExpand`:

[image]

Comment: You're right. That must've been some instance of symbol-blindness or the like... Stared too much at longish expressions and couldn't realize that the disturbing `Abs` does not lead to any longer expressions if expanded... Thank you!